# Why is a section of a sheaf over closed set defined this way?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, definition, sheaf-theory

Why is a section of a sheaf $F$ over closed set $S \subset X$ is defined as inductive limit $$ \varinjlim_{S\subset U} F(U)\; ?$$
From my point of view, we should define it as a function, which each point $x \in S$ maps to $F_x$, such that $S$ can be covered by open sets $U_i$, and there are sections $s_i \in F(U_i)$, which coincide in stalks. Is it equivalent? Maybe, for sufficiently good topological spaces?

Comment: For that function to make sense, $F_x$ would have to be a set of some sort.

Comment: I am interested mostly in sheaves of abelian groups.

Comment: To rephrase, sections of $\left.F\right|_{S}$ are continuous sections of the espace étalé associated to $F$ (continuous with respect to the subspace topology on $Z$ aka the initial topology induced by inclusion).

Comment: The colimit formula does not generally define a sheaf (even when applied to a sheaf). Consequently it is not adjoint to the pushforward of *sheaves*, so there's no high-brow reason to use it as a definition. Upon sheafifying, the colimit formula does produce the left adjoint to direct image of sheaves. This coincides with your proposed definition because inverse image can be calculated by pulling back the associated étalé bundles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your point of view  for the definition of $\Gamma (S, F)$ and thus implicitly for $F\mid S $ is indeed the correct one.

The formula   $\Gamma (S, F)= \varinjlim_{S\subset U} F(U)$ should not be taken as the definition, even though it is is  true in some cases, for exmple   if $X$ is paracompact: cf. Corollaire 1 to Théorème 3.3.1, page 151 of Godement's [Topologie Algébrique et Théorie des Faisceaux](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Topologie_alg%C3%A9brique_et_th%C3%A9orie_des_fa.html?id=JVrvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y).

Comment: Dear @Potato:  on the contrary!  Mumford defines the restriction of a sheaf to a closed subset *exactly* as suggested by the OP, and not as a direct limit: see top of  page 24 of the Red Book.

Comment: Forgive me, I egregiously misread the question.

Comment: No problem, @Potato,  I'm happy to see we agree.

Comment: I was left an exercise which is a far generalization of the theorem you've quoted: Suppose that $j\colon Y\to X$ is a topological embedding, and $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf over $X$, then the presheaf inverse image $j^\dagger\mathscr F$ is a sheaf. In the other words, $\Gamma(j^{-1}\mathscr F,U)=\varinjlim_{V\supseteq j(U)}\mathscr F(V)$. I have no idea to solve this.

Comment: Dear @Yai0Phah I don't think the assertion in your comment holds for arbitrary topological spaces, although it does hold when $X$ is a topological manifold. This and more criteria are given in Proposition 9.1 of Wedhorn's *Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology*.

Comment: @Arrow Thanks for that. Are there any criteria for more algebro-geometric applications (for Zariski topology, or other topologies when one is interested in an immersion of schemes)?

Comment: @Yai0Phah haha I have no idea! I have so little confidence in this stuff that I asked about something related [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3262501/223002).

Answer (score 0):

(I am very new to this, so please don't accept anything written here without thinking about it yourself! These are just my thoughts on this identity and how I might show it.) You can think of a sheaf as a bundle of germs $\Lambda F$ sitting over $X$, with a projection map $p:\Lambda F \rightarrow X$ sending $p(germ_x f) = x$. This bundle is topologized so that  all the sections on $U$ of the form $s_f(x) = germ_x f$ for $f \in F(U)$ are continuous. (The images of these maps are actually taken as a subbasis for the topology, if I recall.) Sections of $F$ over $S$ then correspond to continuous lifts of the inclusion $i:S \hookrightarrow X$ through $p$. I believe each lift corresponds exactly to one of the functions you describe, so we can simply think of lifts.

The question now becomes: can we extend lifts to an open set about $S$? Perhaps this is where the paracompactness condition enters. Given a lift $l$ from $S$ up into the bundle, we obtain lots of information about it in the form of open sets about points in $S$ on which $l$ looks like a map of the form $l(x) = germ_x f$. Perhaps we can then control this using paracompactness and extend $l$ to an open set about $S$, giving the desired equality.